# Как получить отредактированную пользователем строку QTableWidget в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qtablewidget

Я создаю программу, где пользователь, изменив значение клетки таблицы, изменяет ее значение в базе данных.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как получить строку, в которой находится измененная клетка. 
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```py
import sys


from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget, QWidget, QGridLayout


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.columns = ["Id", "Название", "Цена"]
        self.data = [
            [1, "Хлеб", 30],
            [2, "Сок", 35],
            [3, "Мороженое", 15]
        ]

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        central_widget = QWidget(self)         
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)  
 
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()            
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)  

        table = QTableWidget(self)

        table.setColumnCount(3)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        table.setRowCount(3)

        for i, row in enumerate(self.data):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(column)))

        table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        grid_layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QTableWidget.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget.cellChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QTableWidget::**`cellChanged`**(int row, int column)
>
> Этот сигнал излучается всякий раз, когда данные элемента в ячейке, указанной строкой и столбцом, изменились.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem, QTableWidget, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.columns = ["Id", "Название", "Цена"]
        self.data = [
            [1, "Хлеб", 30],
            [2, "Сок", 35],
            [3, "Мороженое", 15]
        ]

        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        central_widget = QWidget(self)         
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)  
 
        grid_layout = QGridLayout()            
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)  

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(3)
        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.columns)
        self.table.setRowCount(3)

        for i, row in enumerate(self.data):
            for j, column in enumerate(row):
                self.table.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(column)))

        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        
        self.table.currentItemChanged.connect(self.current_item_changed) 
        self.table.cellChanged.connect(self.cell_changed)                

        self.current = None
        self.previous = None
        
    def cell_changed(self, row, column):
        print(f'\nИзменились данные элемента в ячейке, строка={row}, столбец={column}')
        print(f'В ячейке было={self.current}, '
              f'стало={self.table.currentItem().text()}')        

    def current_item_changed(self, current, previous):
        # print(f'current = {current}, previous = {previous}')
        self.current = current.text() if current else ''
        self.previous = previous.text() if previous else ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @ОсмановОсман  пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Может быть Вам сделать вверху надпись с помощью переменной и QLabel, а внизу поле для ввода текста. Что то вроде: если пользователь вводит текст и нажимает Enter, то label = новый_текст.

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы менять можно было по двойному щелчку, но спасибо за попытку помочь!

Comment: Ясно. Удачи Вам!

Comment: Anaconda, нет, ваш ответ не правильный.

Answer (score -1):

Создай отдельную переменную, которая  принимает значение из виджета клетки.
Примерно Так:

```
Variable1 = tableVariable.get()
```

Поправь меня, если я неправильно понял вопрос

Comment: Я привел выше код таблицы. Пользователь по двойному щелчку может изменить значение клетки. Но я не знаю, какое событие использовать, чтобы отследить изменение таблицы и как получить экземпляр измененной клетки

Comment: Хмм, тогда вы можете инициализировать два двумерных массива, первый(это поточный массив в который могут вноситься изменения, и второй в котором бы хранились начальные значения. Также добавьте кнопку сохранения , которая бы вызывала функцию которая для начало сохраняет все значения клеток в первый массив и сравнивает его со вторым масивом,  и если какая то клетка не совпадает с начальной - вернуть её значение. Но это чисто моё решение, чем мог тем помог

Comment: Спасибо, я понял!

Comment: Vladislav_Rosch, нет, ваш ответ не правильный.

Comment: S. Nick Вполне мозможно, я это не отрицаю. Я знаю что есть способы куда проще и практичней, но я предоставил только тот, который может почмочь и который я знаю